# Jquery: Show | Hide Div if Hash and Div ID match?

Tags: jquery, hash, hide, anchor, show

I'm trying to create a jquery function that checks the URL hash link and match it to a Div ID which shows or hides the DIV on load. I searched around but haven't found a solid fix.

Comment: Are you using a specific Javascript library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood what you meant, but if you want to hide the current page's nav link for example...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  url = document.location.href;
  hash = url.split('#');
  $('#'+hash[1]).hide();
});
```